# What are fitted.values in Cumulative Link Mixed Models (CLMM) in R?

Tags: r, ordinal-data, ordered-logit

I am estimating a Cumulative Link Mixed Model (CLMM) in R on a dataset similar to the following:

| Likert | Age | Income | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Uncomfortable | 65 | High | East |
| Comfortable | 42 | Low | West |
| Comfortable | 68 | Low | Center |
| Neutral | 75 | High | East |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

The code I use to estimate the model is:

```r
m = clmm(Likert ~ 1 + Age + Income + (1|Location), data = d, 
      threshold = "flexible")
```

My question is what do the `fitted.values` represent in this model? If I run `fitted.values(m)` a numeric list with values between 0 and 1 are outputted. How can I interpret these values?

The [Ordinal package documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ordinal/ordinal.pdf) defines `fitted.values` as

> fitted values evaluated with the random effects at their conditional modes

but I don't understand what this really represents about my dependent variable.

Comment: Apparently, `fitted.values()` of a `polr` object outputs a matrix, with a column for each level of the response. I don't know why `CLMM` only outputs a list!

Comment: As an aside what about `location` makes you treat it as a random effect?

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the vignette for the `clm` function (assuming `clmm` works similarly), [clm_article.pdf](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ordinal/vignettes/clm_article.pdf), it looks like it's returning the predicted probability of the *observed* outcome level for each observation. As mentioned by Amir H, `polr` from `MASS` returns a matrix with the predicted probabilities of each possible outcome level (not just the observed level for that row).

Comment: This predicted probably can be used for residuals for diagnostic purposes as in the Li-Shepherd residuals.  But the `polr` output is more useful in practice since it provides the matrix of all predicted probabilities, i.e., you get as columns all values of $y$ with $\Pr(Y=y)$.